# Loop for deleting large amount

Tags: oracle, loops, delete-row, large-data-volumes

I need to delete 20 million records out of 50 records in the fastest manner possible. I tried to make this work using the loop below :

```
LOOP
  DELETE FROM dssoti.appt_purge WHERE to_date(substr(apntmt_dt,0,9)) < '01-JAN-17' AND ROWNUM < 200000;
  EXIT WHEN SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0;
  COMMIT;
END LOOP;
```

But when I execute this it does not loop, it only deletes 199,999 records. What am I doing wrong here? I'm working in oracle SQL developer version 18

Comment: Why are you putting the delete within a loop to begin with?  Are you performing other logic?

Comment: Additionally, there is an AskTom article on how to delete things quickly.  Take a look: [AskTOM](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2345591157689).  It specifically warns against your loop construct.

Comment: Just to be clear. You are saying the code inside the loop is executed once? How do you know?

Comment: After it executes the script output says "deleted 199,999 records" and when I count the records to confirm it is accurate.

Comment: There is no loop at all since conditions are satisfied it deletes in one go.You wanted to delete one by one or say every 100000 records or whatever number you prefer?

Comment: My intentions were to delete 200,000 records and commit each time until all 20 mil were gone

Comment: My bad I'm really bad at reading zeroes you wanted to delete in batches use for loop for 20 Million for every 200,000 i.e `for in 1..100 loop delete ....;end loop;`

Comment: In addition to the other issues raised, you are comparing a STRING to a DATE (WHERE to_date(substr(apntmt_dt,0,9)) < '01-JAN-17').  That will force oracle to do some implied to_date and to_char functions that may or may not produce the results you expect.  And if it ends up actually comparing strings instead of dates, you don't want the day to be the leading end of it.  Also, please use 4-digit years.  22 years ago I and countless others were busting our a** to avoid the problems cause by 2-digit years.  Please don't repeat the mistakes.

Comment: Yep Sam, but the query is only executing once instead of looping

Answer (score 0):

`rownum = 200000` is not less than 200,000 so you are ending up deleting the 199,999 records only.

You need to use `ROWNUM <= 200000` as follows:

Updated the code for loop issue

```
FOR I IN (SELECT trunc(count(1)/200000) +1 from dssoti.appt_purge 
   WHERE to_date(substr(apntmt_dt,0,9)) < '01-JAN-17')
LOOP
  DELETE FROM dssoti.appt_purge 
   WHERE to_date(substr(apntmt_dt,0,9)) < '01-JAN-17' AND ROWNUM <= 200000; -- change this
  --EXIT WHEN SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0;
  COMMIT;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: I'm fine with it only deleting 199,999 at a time, the issue is that it is not performing the loop, just deleting the one set of records

Comment: same results & :
```Error starting at line : 1 in command -
FOR I IN (SELECT trunc(count(1)/200000) +1 from dssoti.appt_purge
Error report -
Unknown Command

SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP
and to leave enter EXIT.

Error starting at line : 2 in command -
   WHERE to_date(substr(apntmt_dt,0,9)) < '01-JAN-17')
Error report -
Unknown Command


Error starting at line : 3 in command -
LOOP
Error report -
Unknown Command


200,000 rows deleted.


Commit complete.


Error starting at line : 8 in command -
END LOOP
Error report -
Unknown Command```

Comment: @MariaBoggi Hope this is not a production,please make sure you're testing on small sample table in Dev environment sometimes accidentally end up deleting whole table.If possible post complete code in sql developer and data type of aptmnt_dt.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was not including `begin` and `end` before and after the script